# Change the file format used by to_sql method

Tags: amazon-athena, presto, trino, pyathena

This works as expected and creates a new table. But the data is stored in a format that only spark can read. How do I store the data in csv format?

```
from pyathena.pandas.util import to_sql

to_sql(
    mrdf,
    "mrdf_table3",
    conn,
    "s3://" + bucket + "/tutorial/s3dir3/",
    schema="hunspell",
    index=False,
    if_exists="replace",
)
```

I tried  **flavor="csv"** or **flavor="textfile"** but the file that is generated is still not readable.

---

Update: Connection string

```
from pyathena import connect
bucket = "hunspell"

conn = connect(
    aws_access_key_id="XXX",
    aws_secret_access_key="XXX",
    s3_staging_dir="s3://" + bucket + "/tutorial/staging/",
    region_name="us-east-1",
)
```

Comment: What is the connection string of the engine you use?

Comment: @ChananelP added the connection string.

Comment: Perhaps this conn may work `conn_str = "awsathena+rest://:@athena...` see https://pypi.org/project/pyathena/